# Removing string using start and end values

Tags: java, android

I have a string that I want to remove a section from.

The section I want to remove starts in `<img width` and ends with the first instance of `/>`

I want to remove this whole img tag completely.

I've got the following but it requires an entire string to remove whereas I only have the start and end, as the middle changes.

```
String string = var.replace("string to replace but dont have entire", "");
```

Comment: where is your try?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because lack of effort of OP

Comment: Lack of effort? What I had didn't seem relevant. I've updated to question showing what I have and need.

Comment: I vote before you update the question. next time you should provide all things at once when you ask an question. And put input and what is your expected out put.

Comment: its for JavaScript or native android ?

Comment: @SilentKiller native android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String.replaceAll way :

```
    String text = "… \n … <img width … /> → \n…";
    text = text.replaceAll("<img[\\d\\D]*?/>", ""));
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Any links to a read up on what you've done there? What is [\\d\\D]*? doing? Thanks :)

Comment: In regular expression, a dot '.' represent any character except newline s '\n', unless you use the Pattern.DOTALL of java.util.regex.Pattern API. But with replaceAll, you haven't flags and the expression [\d\D] represent numeric and non-numeric character, newline included => all character. It works also with [\w\W] and other that/not-that. All about regular expression here : http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: You can use the embedded version of `Pattern.DOTALL`, `(?s)`: `text.replaceAll("(?s)<img.*?/>", "")`

Comment: Very much appreciate that explanation. Thanks for the link @Alexander_Winter

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy understandable approach:
*(of course using a regular expression would be better)*

```
int beginOFImageTag = var.indexOf("<img width");
int endOfImageTag = var.indexOf("/>", beginOFImageTag + 10); //"+10" because "<img width" has 10 chars

String string = var.substring(0, beginOFImageTag) + var.substring(endOfImageTag + 2, var.length());
```

Comment: Thanks, @NicoA380 answered the question and it worked before this one. I'll see if this works too :)

Comment: @Luke no problem! :) there was a small error, fixed it